# How to change text in another div by clicking on different icons

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm mainly an inbound marketer, but I'm good at HTML and CSS. My knowledge doesn't go beyond these two.

I'm currently building a homepage for my business. I'm stuck at this point.

I have the main homepage with six icons which represent a different benefit.

I want a separate `div` placed below, which will respond to the icons being clicked by changing text.

The best example of a website doing this is Kiss Metrics on their [Homepage](http://www.kissmetrics.com).

I do not know JS or jQuery, is there any way this can be done using CSS?

Comment: What does *"I'm not a Javascript or JQuery ready."* mean? Does it mean you don't want to use JavaScript, and only use CSS?

Comment: This can't be done with **CSS** only.

Comment: I don't think you can do this just with CSS. You can use CSS to make changes to the element that you click on, but you need Javascript to have it affect other elements.

Comment: It means I don't know Javascript or JQuery yet. I don't mind using Javascript to this action but I would be out of my comfort zone

Comment: The javascript can be as simple as one line, so don't worry about that. start by writing your html and css. write all your different text's in a separate div each, `display: hidden` them all, then we'll shou you how to swap which one is display when a button is clicked.

Comment: If it can't be done using Javascript is there a template for the code on Javascript?

Comment: [How to hide div by onclick using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177582/how-to-hide-div-by-onclick-using-javascript).

Comment: It IS (partly) possible to achieve using css only. See my answer below.

Comment: Hi Roy and Bennet_an http://jsfiddle.net/HedpA/20/. I have done a rough version of what I may use. What would be the next steps to get things to work like the kiss metrics site

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with jQuery:

```
$("#imgDiv1").click(function () {
  $("#textDiv2", "#textDiv3", "#textDiv4", "#textDiv5", "#textDiv6").hide();
  $("#textDiv1").show();
});
```

**code explanation:** for each image div you assign a click function to hide all other textDivs and show desired div.

Comment: hi Henser I have a small script

Comment: $('#icon-slideshow').find('li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent usual hyperlink click behavior (changing location)
    
    // hide all but the clicked one
    $('#icon-text').children('div').hide();

    // find div to show
    var div = (this.href.match(/#(.+)/)[1]);
    
    $('#' + div).show();
});

$('#txt1').show();

Comment: it works on jfiddle but doesn't work on the brwser

Answer (score 1):

Actually this **IS** possible using CSS3 only, thanks to `:target` - you can apply different styles for targeted elements onclick.

**[Live jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CAkU7/1/)**

**html:**

```
<div id="icons">
  <a href="#txt1">ICON1</a>
  <a href="#txt2">ICON2</a>
  <a href="#txt3">ICON3</a>
</div>
<div id="text">
  <span id="txt1">Benefit 1</span>
  <span id="txt2">Benefit 2</span>
  <span id="txt3">Benefit 3</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#text span {
  display:none;
}
#text span:target {
  display:block;
}
```

**Please note:**

1. The text will disappear as soon as an element outside of `#icons` is clicked.
2. It's really recommended doing this kind of tasks using jQuery. It's really easy, try it.

Comment: Thanks Roy. I tried using the #links in my browser but they don'y seem to work with the file

Comment: It works on JFiddle but on normal browser

Comment: Let me be clearer. How am I supposed to make the link "#text1", "#text2" links work, so that the text responds

Comment: I created a jfiddle here but it doesn't seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/HedpA/20/

Comment: how do i get the text to respond and how would javascript work?

Comment: Remove the pound characters from your ids - e.g <div id="txt1"> instead of <div id="#txt1">

Comment: Ah Thank You. I just did that, my lack of attention. Now that is done I notice that the link dragging the page down toward the .

Comment: How can javscript or jquery be used improve it to make it similar to kiss metrics?

Comment: you can go with something like henser's answer. But there are more efficient solutions, research further in stackoverflow or google.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have an extensive experience of javascript yet, I must say that this will be solely accomplished by using javascript. I'm a web developer student and speaking of experience, HTML & CSS really just focused more on structuring/styling.

Answer (score 0):

Without JavaScript - no.

With JavaScript you may use

```
document.getElementById('elementId').style.display='none'
```

to make an element disappear, and

```
document.getElementById('elementId').style.display='block'
```

to make it appear.

jQuery would be a better solution anyway.